# Send ONE Javascript variable to PHP via AJAX

Tags: ajax

I've been looking around the forums without a solution to my problem. It's pretty simple, really, and I'd appreciate it if you could explain your answer if you would be so kind.

I'm new to AJAX and Javascript, and I need to send one variable from my javascript code and basically "convert" it into php. Here's what I have so far:

```
var selected = rowData.ID

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { selected },
    cache: false
});
```

I use this selected value further down in the code. I use PHP to display the (value of selected).

```
"vars": [ 
    "(value of selected)" 
],
```

However, I can't seem to make my ajax request work and send the variable to my PHP file. Here's what my PHP file looks like:

```
$row = $_POST["selected"];
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your "data:" with this:

```
 data: { 'selected': selected },
```

Comment: works fine on my server. I can only suggest checking script error in other scripts on the same page and adding success call back to debug: success: function (data) { alert(data); }

Answer (score 0):

So this is very delayed answer, but I was having trouble getting a variable to send too.  I'm not using php, but saw loads of examples like vlscanner gave, but who knows why it didn't work.

I stumbled across this explanation of how to send multiple parameters, and it works just as lovely for sending one parameter.
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods

multiple:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Album: album, User: user, UserToken: userToken }),
```

or  just one:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ Album: album}),
```

I'm no expert on timing,efficiency and all that, and it's possible that JSON.stringify adds unnecessary bulk and there is possibly some valid reason that sending data without the JSON.stringify didn't work.  However, if you are in a bind and need something to work, this might help those of us still asking this question.

I'm suspecting that mine did not work because I was sending it to an asp method that likely requires the parameters to come as a JSON string. I have to research that next. Every step is a new discovery.